# Cannot connect to remote SFTP server using Net_SFTP

Tags: php, sftp

I am trying to connect to a remote server using:

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP($sftp_server,$port_no);
```

The `$port_no` and `$sftp_server` are correct. I can use the same to SFTP to the server using FileZilla.

However when using Net_SFTP, `$sftp->login` fails.
I get the error:

```sh
Cannot connect to $sftp_server:$port_no. Error -446736096. Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

When I do `$sftp->getLog()` it is blank.

Comment: Your error message seems to suggest you've prefixed your sftp server hostname with `https://`. Don't do that. Also, intstead of replacing your parameters with variable names, just neuter the info to `foo.example.com` or something so we can more easily spot the problem next time.

Comment: Sammitch's hunch sounds right. `https` is a different protocol than `sftp`

Comment: That is the solution! Thankyou! I could establish the connection however when I do $sftp->put the process hangs. Looks like it is waiting to put the file but can’t. Get a ‘Expected SSH_FXP_STATUS’ message

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I added the protocol in the host name:

```
sftp://subdomain.domain.com
```

I changed to:

```
subdomain.domain.com
```

And it started to work.